# How do I stop IntelliJ Cursive from re-formating my Clojure code?

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, editor, cursive

How do I stop IntelliJ Cursive from re-formating my Clojure code?  
I'll be staring at a function, realize where I missed a parenthesis, put it in, and BAM! my code is now all re-indented!  
I DON'T WHAT IT TO DO THAT!  
I like my code the way I laid it out!  
I don't want Cursive's formatting help unless I *ask* for it!

Comment: Can you give some examples with code please?

Maybe your issue is in "Structural style", try to change to "Structural Off" and writing some code. You can change this option at the bottom bar in the right side, after the branch's name.

Comment: I think it is _off_ as structural editing would prevent missing parens (not a cursive user here, but an intellij one). That could as well be just intellij reindenting when blocks are closed (like it does non-clojure files too)

Comment: Thanks to you both for being willing to help.

Comment: I tried to duplicate the problem and, of course, it won't now. BTW, "Structural Editing" is turned off if the "Structural Off" in the lower-right means anything. I tried that first. We'll see how long it goes before it happens again, and I can send Before&After screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I found something.
Settings --> Editor --> Code Style --> Clojure...
This last option may only be present if you've installed the "Cursive" plug-in for Clojure code.
There is a HUGE list of indents and tab/spaces settings. 
I set everything to zero (0). 
That seems to be holding, so far.